# How can I make a file upload required (asp .NET), only if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a working file upload control, but I need the file upload to be required only if a checkbox is checked. So, if the user checks "I have the file", then they must also upload a file. If they don't check the box, the file upload is not required.

The biggest problem with my code below is when the user browses to select a file and then clicks 'upload', haveFileValidation() is triggered, and at that point no file has been uploaded yet (because btnUpload_Click hasn't happened yet). I think I need a way to not do the validation if the upload button was clicked, but DO the validation if my submit button was clicked?

Here's what I have tried so far:

aspx:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server"  />
                  
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"  />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uplValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUpload" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"
 ErrorMessage="xls, xlsx, doc, docx, ppsx, pptx, txt, csv, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif, tif formats are allowed"  ValidationGroup="fleUpload"
 ValidationExpression="^.*\.(xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX|doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|ppsx|PPSX|pptx|PPTX|txt|TXT|csv|CSV|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|tif|TIF|pdf|PDF)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="haveFileValidator" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="file is required" OnServerValidate="haveFileValidation">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void haveFileValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
        args.IsValid = true;
        if (chkHaveFile.Checked)
        {
            //args.IsValid = (gvFiles.Rows.Count > 0);
            args.IsValid = (fileUpload.HasFile);
        }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }
    UploadFile(int.Parse(txtID.Text));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like great UX to me. Why not change the message on the page to say "Upload a file if you have one" and only validate against the file type etc. if they do upload a file ? (i.e. if fileUpload.hasFile)

Comment: The requirement is to make the file upload required if they check the box. The department asking for this change has had to contact the user each time when they say they have the file, but then don't upload it.